# Simple JavaScript Regex replace is not working on Token with Square Brackets?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace the token "[RANDOMNUMBER]" in a string but my code is not working? The regex shows as valid when checking on online validation tools? I know it has to be a stupid mistake but I don't see it?

```
function detokenizeTags(imgSrc){
    var rn = Math.random() + "",
    rnd = rn * 10000000000000;
    imgSrc.replace(/\[RANDOMNUMBER\]/g,rnd);
    return imgSrc; 
}
```

sample input string:   //ad.amgdgt.com/ads/?t=ap&px=79079&rndn=[RANDOMNUMBER]

Comment: And how is it being called exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the fact the replacement does NOT change the original string.

```
imgSrc.replace(/\[RANDOMNUMBER\]/g,rnd);
```

needs to be

```
imgSrc = imgSrc.replace(/\[RANDOMNUMBER\]/g,rnd);
```

---

```js
function detokenizeTags(imgSrc){
    var rn = Math.random() + "",
    rnd = rn * 10000000000000;
    return imgSrc.replace(/\[RANDOMNUMBER\]/g,rnd);
}

var str = "//ad.amgdgt.com/ads/?t=ap&px=79079&rndn=[RANDOMNUMBER]";

console.log(str, detokenizeTags(str));
```

Comment: I knew I was doing something stupid! That's what I get for being up for almost two days! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`.replace` doesn't modify the string, it returns a new string.  Instead of:

```
imgSrc.replace(/\[RANDOMNUMBER\]/g,rnd);
return imgSrc;
```

try just:

```
return imgSrc.replace(/\[RANDOMNUMBER\]/g,rnd);
```